# How to detect if current scope has a parent in CMake?

Tags: cmake, cmake-scopes

Is there any way to detect if the current scope has a parent?

I have a project that can either be a standalone project or a sub-project of another. To allow the sub project case, I use the PARENT_SCOPE flag to set() to push things up to the parent. However, when build as a standalone project I get a "current scope has no parent" warning. I would like to avoid that error by detecting if there is a parent and enclosing the set() calls in an if statement. Or is there another way to set a variable at parent scope only if there is a parent?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think the most robust approach is to use the [`PARENT_DIRECTORY`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_dir/PARENT_DIRECTORY.html) directory property.

This will yield the correct answer regardless of whether it's called before or after the `project` command, and regardless of whether the parent and child both have the same project name.

```
get_directory_property(hasParent PARENT_DIRECTORY)
if(hasParent)
  message(STATUS "Has a parent scope.")
else()
  message(STATUS "Doesn't have a parent scope.")
endif()
```

Answer (score 11):

CMake version 3.21 added the [`PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL.html#variable:PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL) global variable for this:

> A boolean variable indicating whether the most recently called
> project() command in the current scope or above was in the top level
> CMakeLists.txt file.

```
project(my_project)
[...]

if(PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL)
  message(STATUS "Is a top-level project.")
endif()
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding a bit on @ruslo idea
I would not take the `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` but the `CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME` variable (contains the name of the first defined project) and the `PROJECT_NAME` (contains the name of the current project), so you could do something like this in the `CMakeLists.txt` of the Subproject:

```
project(bar)

if(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} STREQUAL ${PROJECT_NAME})
 #do stuff
else()
 #do other stuff
endif()
```

Comment: You can't nest the `if(... STREQUAL ...)` inside the `set` command.

Comment: Good point, I did not think of that and didn't test it. I'll move the test directly in the if. Btw good call with the `PARENT_DIRECTORY` property. I did not know that exists.