# How can I tell, within a CMakeLists.txt, whether it's used with add_subdirectory()?

Tags: build, cmake, subdirectory, subrepos

I have this code project can be built either independently or as a subproject of a larger repository (checking it our as a sub-repository). In the latter case, I have a top-level `CMakeLists.txt` for the main project which has

```
add_subdirectory(${MY_SUBPROJ_SUBDIR})
```

now, I want the subproject to behave somewhat differently in case it's used via `the add_directory()`. Obviously, I would be using a large `if` instruction. But what condition do I check? How can CMake "tell", when running for some `CMakeLists.txt`, whether it's a subdir file or the main file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. **After** the `project()` call in project's `CMakeLists.txt` and in the project's subdirectories you may use:

   ```
    if(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR)
        # I am top-level project.
    else()
        # I am called from other project with add_subdirectory().
    endif()
   ```

   **NOTE**: As stated in the comments, this approach may to not work on Windows, where `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` contains lower-case version of `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` and thus cannot be compared directly for equality. For that case approach with checking `PARENT_DIRECTORY` property, as described in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25217937/3440745) to the duplicate question, seems to be more robust.
2. Alternative for use **before** the `project()` call:

   ```
    if(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR)
        # I am top-level project.
    else()
        # I am called from other project with add_subdirectory().
    endif()
   ```

   This alternative can also be used anywhere in project's `CMakeLists.txt` (but not in subdirectories).

---

Assume you have a project *A* with two `CMakeLists.txt`: one in the project's directory, and one in subdirectory `src/`. Scheme for use approaches described above:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(...)
...
<only approach *2* can be used there>
...
project(A)
...
<approach *1* or *2* can be used there>
...
add_subdirectory(src)
...
```

**src/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
...
<only approach *1* can be used there>
...
```

With given scheme project *A* may detect, whether it is built standalone (top-level project) or as a part of another project *B*.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.

Comment: Just a hint: When using `PROJEC_SOURCE_DIR` it means CMake has already parsed your sub-directories `project()` command. Alternatively you can find `if(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR)` (see e.g. [here](https://github.com/preshing/junction/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) or [here](https://github.com/ufz-vislab/VtkFbxConverter/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt)),

Comment: @Florian: I wanted to write the same, but was interrupted. Now the post is updated. Thanks.

Comment: The repositories shouldn't really make assumptions about whether or not we will even have a project call, or in which order.

Comment: None project has assumptions about its caller. By `project()` call I mean the **call from the project itself**, not from the callers. I have edited the post, probably you find it more clear.

Comment: I needed to use `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`, not `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`

Comment: @sourcedelica That will always return true in the same file as the `project()` call.

Comment: This doesn't work on Windows. `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` expands to `c:/users/...`, but `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` expands to `C:/Users/...`. Instead of `STREQUAL`, one has to do a case insensitive comparison (convert both strings to lowercase, then do `STREQUAL`)

Comment: `string(TOLOWER ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} source_dir)
string(TOLOWER ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} current_source_dir)
if(${source_dir} STREQUAL ${current_source_dir})
  message(STATUS "not in subdirectory")
else()
  message(STATUS "in subdirectory")
endif()`

Comment: Newer CMake provides `PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL` variable

Comment: @MariuszJaskółka: This variable is already described in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68820462/3440745) to the duplicate question.