# Given a CMakeLists file, is there any way to know which parent CMakeLists 'called' it?

Tags: cmake

Given a big `cmake` project, let `B` be a `CMakeLists.txt`, located at some directory within it. Is there any way to print (`message(...)`) from within `B` which parent `CMakeLists.txt` file did the `add_subdirectory(B)` or equivalent?

**Note:** Let's suppose that no `cmake` files do literally `add_subdirectory(B)`, but rather `add_subdirectory(${X})`, being `X` the path to subdirectory `B`, determined through the `cmake` tree somehow. Otherwise, this could be determined just with `grep`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property [PARENT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/prop_dir/PARENT_DIRECTORY.html) contains parent source directory:

```
get_directory_property(parent_dir PARENT_DIRECTORY)
if (parent_dir)
    message(STATUS "I am called with 'add_subdirectory' from script ${parent_dir}/CMakeLists.txt")
else ()
    message(STATUS "I am top-level CMakeLists.txt script)
endif()
```

See also [How to detect if current scope has a parent in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199677/how-to-detect-if-current-scope-has-a-parent-in-cmake)

Comment: If the child CMake file was added via `include()` or `find_package()`, the `PARENT_DIRECTORY` property will also return empty string. So for these cases, you can instead use [`CMAKE_PARENT_LIST_FILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/variable/CMAKE_PARENT_LIST_FILE.html) to obtain the full path to the parent CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: Yes, `PARENT_DIRECTORY` works only for inclusion via `add_subdirectory()`. And `CMAKE_PARENT_LIST_FILE` works only for inclusions via `include()` and `find_package()`.