# Problem using FetchContent_Declare together with shared library

Tags: cmake

I'm having problem using `FetchContent_Declare` with a shared library. I'm trying to apply a modular design (instead of creating one mega-repository with 20 modules I'm allocating a dedicated repository to each module). I'm trying to use `FetchContent_Declare` in order to link dependant modules together (I'm not a fan of git-submodules since those require that user manually initialises them). The problem I'm having is that the DLL generated by the project *fetched* via the mentioned function isn't copied to the binary output of the parent project. Here is a dependency graph to make it more clear.

```
Repo A:
- bin
- bin-etc
- lib
- include
    - project_a
        .. header files ..
- src
   - CMakeLists.txt : 1
   .. source files ..
- CMakeLists.txt : 2

Repo B: Includes A
- bin
- bin-etc
- lib
- output
    .. cmake files are built from here .. 
    - _deps
        - project_a-src
            - bin 
                .. here the DLL file is being generated .. 
- include
    - project_a
        .. header files ..
- src
   - CMakeLists.txt : 3
   .. source files ..
- CMakeLists.txt : 4
```

The DLL file is being generated in `./output/_deps/project_a-src/bin` instead of `./bin`.

Here are my `CMakeLists.txt` files:

```
# CMakeLists.txt : 1
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

set(PROJECTNAME project_a)
set(PROJECTDIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")

file(GLOB_RECURSE inc "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include/*.hpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE src "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp")

source_group(TREE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include" FILES ${inc})
source_group(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FILES ${src})

if (MSVC)
    add_compile_options(/W3) # warning level 3
    add_compile_options(/MP) # Multi-processor compilation
endif()

add_library(
    ${PROJECTNAME}
    SHARED
    ${inc}
    ${src}
    )

target_include_directories(${PROJECTNAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include/")
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt : 2 and 4

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 10.0.19041.0)

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin-etc")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")

project(project_a LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt : 3
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

set(PROJECTNAME project_b)
set(PROJECTDIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")

file(GLOB_RECURSE inc "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include/*.hpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE inc_src "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.hpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE src "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp")

source_group(TREE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include" FILES ${inc})
source_group(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FILES ${inc_src})
source_group(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FILES ${src})

if (MSVC)
    add_compile_options(/W3) # warning level 3
    add_compile_options(/MP) # Multi-processor compilation
endif()

add_library(
    ${PROJECTNAME}
    SHARED
    ${inc}
    ${inc_src}
    ${src}
    )

target_include_directories(${PROJECTNAME} PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include/")

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(project_a
        GIT_REPOSITORY <REPO LINK>
        GIT_TAG master)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(project_a)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECTNAME} project_a)
```

What would be the solution to this problem? Should I use another approach for the design like this? Is adding a simple `copy` command to cmake the right solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables like `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` affects on the output directory for all further created libraries ... unless the variable is **changed**.

The `project_a` in `CMakeLists.txt`(2) does

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")
```

**unconditionally**, so it changes the variable even if it is built as a subproject (with FetchContent).

Generally, any project in its root `CMakeLists.txt` could check, whether it is actually **top-level project**. And perform some settings only in case it is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

project(project_a LANGUAGES CXX)

if (PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL)
  # Do global settings only if we are top-level project.
  set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

  set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 10.0.19041.0)

  set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin-etc")
  set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib")
  set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")
endif()

# Other settings are treated as project-specific,
# so could be done in "subproject mode" too.
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

---

Note, that variable [PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL.html) appears only in CMake 3.21. For detect, whether the project is top-level in older CMake versions, consult that question and its answers: [How to detect if current scope has a parent in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199677/how-to-detect-if-current-scope-has-a-parent-in-cmake).

Comment: That solves my issue. But I would still like to know if there are better aproaches.